# Should I use factory to update object?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I use factory to create entity by command object, but when I want to update entity from command object, I can't find a good patten to do this. Should I just use factory to update entity, or if not, what is a good pattern?

```
interface ProductFactory {
    Product create(ProductCommand command);
    Product update(Product product, ProductCommand command);
}
```

my service：

```
class ProductServiceImpl {

     public Product updateProduct(long productId, ProductCommand command) {
         Product product = productRepository.findOne(productId);
         product = productFactory.update(product, productCommand);

         return productRepository.save(product);
     }
}
```

Comment: If your domain is mostly CRUD then do not attempt to apply the tactical DDD patterns. Do not attempt to craft a rich domain model. Just have dumb data bags, implement the logic into services directly and use scaffolding tools to generate repetitive code automatically. Believe it or not, that could be the most DDD-aligned solution because at it's core DDD is about properly identifying the sub-domains and solve their problems with the right solutions. Slapping a domain model on everything goes against what DDD promotes.

Comment: Call it a KISS answer, but what in DDD would prevent a class from having its own methods to update its objects? It's known sometimes as the [Do-it-myself pattern](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:tell_don_t_ask_information_expert).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On DDD one of the strategic paterns is the use of ubiquitous language in code. So, in your specific case, the class methods should be named according to what they do, like `Product::changeTitle` or `Priduct::changePrice`:

Also, there are multiple architectural styles. One of them is without a command object but with multiple parameters like this:

```
class ProductService {

     public void changeProductPrice(long productId, double newPrice) {
         Product product = productRepository.findOne(productId);
         product.changePrice(product, newPrice);

        productRepository.save(product);
     }
}
```

This style follows a lot the ubiquitous language.

The other style is with a command object parameter:

```
class ProductCommandHandler {

     public void handleChangeProductPrice(ChangeProductPrice command) {
         Product product = productRepository.findOne(command.getAggregateId ());
         product.handleChangeProductPrice(command);

        productRepository.save(product);
     }
}
```

This second style fits very good with the CQRS+Event sourcing where you could almost eliminate the `Application layer` by extracting a generic `command handler` that identifies and loads the aggregate from the repository, it sends it the command, it collects the events and then persist them to the `Event store`. I use a lot this style.

Comment: thank you for your help, I finally move both create and update method to model class, but it looks messed my model class, I still think this is a common problem in DDD, and don't know what is the best practice, but keep things is model class make it much understandable.

Comment: The most important things in DDD are: the bounded contexts and the ubiquitous language; avoid names like `updateProduct`. It's a good think that you moved them to the model (Aggregate/Entity) in this way your model owns its data, it controls what is is permitted and what is not permitted inside it; also, in this way you protect the encapsulation of the model, an important principle from OOP.

Comment: In my opinion passing commands to aggregates is most likely a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434458/passing-cqrs-commands-directly-to-domain-objects/30445004#30445004). You just said it, the most important thing in DDD is the ubiquitous language. Commands are merely message contracts at the application boundary, they shouldn't belong to the domain. Business experts would certainly be puzzled by `product.handleChangeProductPrice(command)`, but not so much by `product.changePrice(newPrice)`.

Comment: @plalx I respect your oppinion. However, I like that style as it removes **a lot** of code duplication.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu What kind of duplication? Do you have an example? Also, what about value objects? From what I can tell `product.changePrice(new Price(command.price))` is much simpler than `product.handleChangeProductPrice(command)` which has to do the mapping internally anyway. No?

Comment: @plalx *all* Application services/layer. The example is my in-production micro-framework https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-es

Comment: Oh ok I get what you mean, you do not have to load the AR etc. Well, it does remove a lot of plumbing, but it also comes at a cost. I can't really tell which is better, but your approach is definitely more technical and less aligned with DDD and the ubiquitous language overall I think.

Answer (score 5):

The *naming* alone answers your question. A **factory** is responsible for *creating* things. Yes, in the real world, sometimes factories take back things they created to update them (think of German car manufacturers here).

But in case of software, turning your factory into a "maintenance station" seems like bad practice. It clashes with the single responsibility principle for example. Beyond that - a factory that updates objects is very uncommon - thus surprising to the human readers of the source code. And you want to avoid *surprising* people reading your code.

My suggestion: staying in line with the "service" theme I already mentioned: would it make sense introduce an *UpdateService* class for example? Of course, when there is *common* code for update and create, then that should again be factored out into a common class.

Comment: thanks, but if I create a separate class, how can I reuse the code both required for create and update.

Comment: By factoring out the common parts in another class?

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I finally end with the Rich Domain Model things, and move both create and update method to model class.

Comment: You are welcome. It is always nice to see questions that provoke further thinking - and to see how helpful but *diverse* answers come back ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In Domain Driven Design, the application typically interacts with the aggregate root directly.

```
 public Product updateProduct(long productId, ProductCommand command) {
     Product product = productRepository.findOne(productId);

     product.update(productCommand);

     return productRepository.save(product);
 }
```

Comment: If Product is a complex object, and I make it only a data class (only have getters/setters), can I put update method in other class, l want to put it in factory because I want to reuse code both in create and update.

Answer (score 1):

Factories are for creating objects, not for updating them.

Updating a entity is a persistence aspect and is done by the repository.

You have to do the following in the application layer:

1) Call the repository to retrieve by id the entity you want to update.

2) Modify the entity properties you want, with the values you get from the command. This is done by calling entity methods that update the properties. You shouldn't do it in the factory. The factory is just for creating the entity. Modifying the entity is a behavior (method) offered by the entity.

3) Call the repository to persist the entity.